# iPhone: How to remove the gridlines that come in background for the core-plot?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, charts, core-plot

How to remove the gridlines that come in background for the core-plot?

I want the background to be of white color with no gridlines.

Currently my core plot looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the black gridlines shown in background.

how can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `majorGridLineStyle` and `minorGridLineStyle` properties on both axes to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your answer did help me. I was not able to find it initially when I went through the code. but your answer just made my work easy. Thanks for that. :]